# loop to check if a file exists

Tags: java, file, loops

I have a folder that must contain always one file **config8**, and if a new file is created in this folder the old file is deleted and replaced by the new file with the same name **config8**.

I write this code

```
       File file1 = new File("/home/olfa/Bureau/config/config8");
       File file2 = new File("/home/olfa/Bureau/config/config9");
      while (file2.exists())
      {
          file1.delete();
          file2.renameTo(file1); }
      }
    serverConnection = new ServerConnection("/home/olfa/Bureau/config/config8");
```

I need to add a loop to check everytime if config9 is created.

Comment: Your opening paragraph implies if _any_ new file is created in the folder. Your concluding remark is if only `config9` is created. What is the exact requirement?

Comment: Your code is very misleadingly laid-out, since you have a closing brace at the end of `file2.renameTo(file1); }`

Comment: I just want to check if config9 is created in every time and thank you for your remark

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a loop try a WatchService.

Basically you would be watching a particular directory for change and then you can react on this change.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

For example :

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                       ENTRY_CREATE,
                       ENTRY_DELETE,
                       ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
System.err.println(x);
}
```

Then you can process your key events.

Comment: You might consider extracting the basics from the link to add to this answer. This one is close to a "link only" and might get tagged in a review.

Comment: I'm using jdk 1.6 and I don't know if WatchService is available or not

Answer (score 0):

If you have to solve this task with Java 1.6, you can use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/, version 2.1.

Here is an example for moving all incoming config files to "config8":

```
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileMonitor;

import java.io.File;

public class ConfigWatcher {
    private static final String configDirName = "target/config";
    private static final String configName = "config8";
    private static final String absoluteConfigName = new File(configDirName + File.separator + configName).getAbsolutePath();
    private FileSystemManager manager = null;
    FileObject configDir = null;
    private FileObject configFile = null;
    private FileChangeEvent lastEvent = null;

    public void watchConfig() throws Exception {
        manager = VFS.getManager();

        DefaultFileMonitor fm = new DefaultFileMonitor(new ConfigFileListener());
        configFile = manager.resolveFile(absoluteConfigName);
        configDir = manager.resolveFile(new File(configDirName).getAbsolutePath());
        fm.setDelay(1000);
        fm.addFile(configDir);
        fm.start();
    }

    class ConfigFileListener implements FileListener {
        public void fileCreated(FileChangeEvent fileChangeEvent) throws Exception {
            FileObject latestConfigFile = fileChangeEvent.getFile();
            String fileBaseName = fileChangeEvent.getFile().getName().getBaseName();
            if (!configName.endsWith(fileBaseName) && !fileChangeEvent.equals(lastEvent)) {
                System.out.println("new config detected - move config");
                latestConfigFile.moveTo(configFile);
            }
            lastEvent = fileChangeEvent;
        }

        public void fileChanged(FileChangeEvent fileChangeEvent) {
        }

        public void fileDeleted(FileChangeEvent fileChangeEvent) {
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ConfigWatcher configWatcher = new ConfigWatcher();
        configWatcher.watchConfig();
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```